# WP Custom Widget <ul> tag is outside

Tags: wordpress, tags, widget, html-lists

i have a problem with Wordpress.
I created a new plugin. I created a widget for my website.
When I try to reflect the data, the ul tag stays outside.

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];


echo '<ul class="categoryarea">' . __( wp_list_categories( array('hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 1, 'title_li' => __( false )))) . '</ul>'; // Problem is here. line
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

Output html image ;

[ul tag is outside (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xKBk.png)

Output html code ;

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-10">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-11">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-20">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-12">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-13">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-14">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-16">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-17">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-18">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-19">...</li>
<ul class="categoryarea"></ul> <-- Problem here
```

what I need is;

```
<ul class="categoryarea">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-10">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-11">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-20">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-12">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-13">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-14">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-16">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-17">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-18">...</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-19">...</li>
</ul> <-- I need help
```

Thank you in advance for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an argument key `echo` that is set `1` by default in the function.

```
echo '<ul class="categoryarea">' . __( wp_list_categories( array('hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 1, 'echo' => 0, 'title_li' => __( false )))) . '</ul>'; // should fix
```

Also you might want to remove the `__();` since this is for translation and usually you would not translate the html generated but the categories themselves, which would be done through other means.

Reference

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

Comment: Thanks for your information and help.it's worked.I wrote the code missing.I am not aware.
"__ ();" I use the code like this.is this a problem ?
####

echo '<ul class="categoryarea">' . __( wp_list_categories( array('hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 1, 'echo' => 0, 'title_li' => __( false ))), 'mkg_widget_domain' ) . '</ul>';

Comment: Not a problem per say but why translate HTML along the way when you can already get the translated categories from the function without calling `__();`

Comment: You're right.Maybe it would make sense to use it if I had written it as text.I removed the __(); function.Php is my new interest.I'm trying to learn while I'm creating new plugin or theme.Thanks again.Now I use the code like this.  ### echo '<ul class="categoryarea">' . wp_list_categories( array('hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 1, 'echo' => 0, 'title_li' => __( 'Secret Categories' ))) . '</ul>';

I'm just using it for the widget title. __( 'Secret Categories' )